# Delete Mulitple Rows Based on Date

Tags: excel, vba

I created a Macro where i delete each row based on the date that it has in Column "C". I am having trouble with the macro cause it goes through each row and deletes them invidually instead of all at once. Is there any way i can speed the process up so that it wont take 30 minutes for it to run. the File is very large by the way.

```
Sub DeleteRowsBeforeCutoff()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    NumRows = Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    Range("A1").Select
    For x = 3 To NumRows
        If Cells(x, 3) < [K1] Then
            Cells(x, 3).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next x
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Run the loop **backwards**

Answer (score 0):

as @Gary's wrote, the code will be loop backwards, 
I tried yr code (updated) ad my to delete each rows into a 25K range row,
this is the result:
mycode:  00:00:03:123
joecode: 00:00:14:1214

Both codes:

```
Sub testJoe()
Dim startTime As Single
Dim i As Long
startTime = Time()
For i = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row To 2 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 3) = 3 Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
Next
Debug.Print Format(Time() - startTime, "HH:nn:ss:ms")
End Sub

Sub mytest()
Dim startTime As Single, rang As Range, sh As Worksheet
startTime = Time()
Set sh = ActiveSheet
sh.UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                        Criteria1:="=3", _
                        VisibleDropDown:=False
Set rang = sh.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0)
Set rang = rang.Resize(rang.Rows.Count - 1)
Set rang = rang.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rang.EntireRow.Delete
Selection.AutoFilter
Debug.Print Format(Time() - startTime, "HH:nn:ss:ms")
End Sub
```